# Convert Gravity Form Entry Date on Export

Tags: hooks, date, plugin-gravity-forms

Gravity Forms offers a hook to modify field values when exporting an entry list using the `gform_export_field_value` hook. They show an example on how to change the User ID to the User Display Name on Export in their [documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_export_field_value/).

I'm looking to change the Date Format for the Entry Date field. Here is what I have so far but doesn't seem to be working:

```
add_filter( 'gform_export_field_value', 'export_entry_date_value', 10, 4 );
function export_entry_date_value( $value, $form_id, $field_id, $entry ) {

    if( $field_id == 'date_created' ) {
        return !empty( $value ) ? date('F', strtotime($value) ) : $value;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Here is information on the hook: [gform_export_field_value](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_export_field_value/)

Any ideas?

Comment: is the _"Entry Date field"_ in question, a date input field that you created? or is it the actual submission date of the gravity form you're after?

Comment: The Entry Date data is created by Gravity Forms and is an default Export data field option. The User ID data is processed the same way... that is why I referenced that option in the documentation. It's NOT a created field in the form, it's data captured by Gravity Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't modify date_created on Export

Gravity Forms `date_created` field isn't actually a field that's affected by that hook. If you look in `/exports.php` you'll find in `start_export()` that they bypass the filter for ID's `date_created` and `payment_date` and hard-code force the use of `Y-m-d H:i:s`

```
foreach ( $leads as $lead ) {
    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): Processing entry #' . $lead['id'] );

    foreach ( $fields as $field_id ) {
        switch ( $field_id ) {
            case 'date_created' :
            case 'payment_date' :
                $value = $lead[ $field_id ];
                if ( $value ) {
                    $lead_gmt_time   = mysql2date( 'G', $value );
                    $lead_local_time = GFCommon::get_local_timestamp( $lead_gmt_time );
                    $value           = date_i18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $lead_local_time, true );
                }
                break;
            default :
                $field = RGFormsModel::get_field( $form, $field_id );

                $value = is_object( $field ) ? $field->get_value_export( $lead, $field_id, false, true ) : rgar( $lead, $field_id );
                $value = apply_filters( 'gform_export_field_value', $value, $form_id, $field_id, $lead );

                ...
```

---

### Instead

You can create a custom field in your form, make it a hidden field, 
then use another [`gform_pre_submission`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_submission/) hook to fill it with your server time on submission.

Being a GravityForms customer, [their support is superior](https://www.gravityforms.com/support/), maybe they've got better tricks up their sleeves. They're also pretty open to suggestions - opening a ticket as a suggestion to add a hook for that date format there might be worth a try.

Comment: Based on the code provided, do you think I can change the `$value` by checking if `$field_id == 'payment_date'`?

Comment: not at all. `date_created` and `payment_date` and hard-coded exceptions - the `break` at the end of their `case` ends their processing within that loop - so there's no chance of them hitting the required filter.

Comment: Ah. I see that the filter is only within the default case, so that would mean the filter doesn't apply to any other case check.

Comment: I'll look into a `gform_pre_submission` hook. I already created a Hidden field for the User Display Name that uses a dynamically populated parameter.